# How to add or subtract certain percent for all values in one Pandas Dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Dataframe that look like this:

```
 feat_1 feat_2  feat_3  
10      42      90  
25      10      19
```

I want to create a function which will add or subtract certain percentage from all of the values for only one column.

So draft would look like this:

```
def change_percentage(df, percent, column): 
     new_df = df.copy()
     new_df[column] += percent
```

I don't know how to get specific percent for each of the values so my desired output would look like this for calling `change_percentage(df=df, percent = 100, column='feat_1')`

```
 feat_1 feat_2  feat_3  
20      42      90  
50      10      19
```

and for example for calling: `change_percentage(df=df, percent = -50, column='feat_2')` desired output is:

```
 feat_1 feat_2  feat_3  
10      21      90  
25      5      19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the series in-place?

```
df["feat2"] *= 0.5  # reduce by half
```

If you really want to make it a function that takes -100..+100 as an argument,

```
def change_percentage(df, column, percent):
    if percent < -100:
        raise ValueError("Percent out of range")
    multiplier = 1 + percent / 100
    df[column] *= multiplier
```

Comment: Thank you :) I were searching for second solution :)